# How to use google cloud functions to import files from winscp? I also want to make triggers associated with this function which executes weekly

Tags: function, google-cloud-functions, cloud, eventtrigger

How to use google cloud functions to import files from winscp? I also want to make triggers associated with this function, which executes weekly to import these files.Please assist.

Comment: Your cannot *"import files from winscp"*. WinSCP is a SFTP/FTP client. You have probably meant that you want to *"import files from SFTP/SCP/whatever server"*.

Answer (score 0):

For a weekly trigger -> Use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler).

Download a file from SSH server, use a SSH library to initiate the traffic from the Cloud Functions to the SCP server. I don't know your language, I can't help you on that.

Keep in mind that the files that you download is stored in memory in the `/tmp` directory (size correctly your Cloud Functions service) and, because it's in memory, the file is not persisted. If you need to persist it, think to put it in a persistent storage, like Cloud Storage.